# How to connect data in remote server with tableau

Tags: sqlite, odbc, tableau-api

I started exploring tableau desktop and I 'd like to connect the data I created in remote linux server hence I’d like to reach experts who already went through this issue and know how to fix.

Here is what I have so far

•                    tableau desktop version 10.3.7(trial version) installed on window

•                    installed sqliteodbc on my desktop

•                    my data is saved in remote server at certain folder I created and I usually access this source via ssh ( ip address and user/pw)

In tableau config as a first step, I get into “other databases(ODBC)” and need to connect using “DSN/Driver”.  I’m not sure how to configure if I want to connect to my remote data source.
e.g. my database file is under /home/te/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz.db  in the remote server and there are tables in the .db files.

Please advise me what I should do as the next.

thanks,

Comment: SQLite is a file-based database. To access a database on a remote server, you must use a network file system. (And sshfs does not run on Windows.)

Comment: thanks for your input CL. my db server is single server. if I install NFS on remote server, what would be the client server? It looks like at least 2 servers required to set up NFS. And If I publish my dash board after connect database, would I be able to share the db with other user who will use published dashboard?

Comment: Windows comes with an NFS client (in the Enterprise/Ultimate editions). But I don't know if that client [implements locking correctly](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_filesystems_with_broken_or_missing_lock_implementations).

Comment: btw, would it be possible to create server and client between linux machine and window desktop? e.g. as my sqlite database resides in linux machine and I'd want to see this db from my window desktop if both ends configured as NFS.

Comment: Yes, there are NFS clients for Windows. As I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: One of the ways you could do this is by establishing a Tunnel from windows desktop to remote linux server (using a tool like putty ).

See this:
https://bigthinkingapplied.com/how_to_do_ssh_tunneling_or_port_forwarding/

Once a tunnel is established you can use the Tableu "other databases ODBC" option to connect to the SQLliteDB . Use Linux Server IP address for SERVER field and  22 for PORT and rest are the DB details.